# How can I measure the response time of a user interaction with my web app?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, web-applications, response-time, tooling

I have a mobile web app and I'd like a method of measuring the time it takes for my app to respond to a user interaction. An example would be measuring the time it takes for a button to change appearance (to show the user that it is clicked) after the initial tap of the button.

I'm not aware of any chrome development tools that can do this, but if you know of any tools or methods of measuring UI response times it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze end-to-end UI latency during page transitions with the Navigation Timing API (W3C specification, more documentation, browser support matrix). These latency measurements could be recorded for a wide swath of users and analyzed in aggregate to get a decent overview of performance for all users.

On the web, the most common choice is probably Selenium, thanks to the large number of language bindings and its array of testing tools. In fact, you should be able to build UI performance checks into a more general suite of regression tests.

Answer (score 0):

You using System.currentTimeMillis() measuring time start and end of application.
Time end - time start = response time of app.